# How to get english datetime from Calendar.getInstance().getTime() in a non-english Locale in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

MY application Locale is persian but i want `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` to return normal english datetime? Is there any way to do it without changing the locale?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH mm ss dd MMM ''yy", Locale.ENGLISH);
String dateOutput = sdf.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `getInstance` with a Locale param.

[getInstance(java.util.Locale)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance(java.util.Locale))

`Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)`